# mongodb messaging - getting one of each

Tags: php, mongodb

I am working on a simple messaging system over mongodb.

Suppose I am user A, having private messages from B and C: in my inbox view I would like to be able to show the last message from each, either sent from me or from B or C;

take the facebook messaging page for instance. That's what I'd like to do.

Currently I have a field called "last.message" where I store the last message sent by any of the two people but, is there a better way to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain 2 collections.

First collection,

```
{ sender: UserA,
  receiver: UserB,
  latest_message: {message: String, timestamp: Date}
}
```

Second collection storing all messages between all users,

```
{ sender: UserA,
  receiver: UserB,
  message: String,
  timestamp: Date
}
```

In first collection only the latest message is written and first collection needs frequent updates. Index can be like `{receiver : 1}` and `{sender : 1}`.

Second collection stores each and every message. This will have frequent inserts. Indexes can be like `{receiver : 1, timestamp : -1}` or `{receiver : 1, sender : 1, timestamp : -1}` depending on your requirements.

Going by this approach you get latest messages from set of friends quite fast and simple. Just 2 simple find queries with no complex condition.
Though there is a small downside, that you need to maintain 2 collection. And for every new message you have 2 writes.
But in my personal opinion its quite clean.

You can also consider using an in-RAM database like Redis to maintain first collection. Though it won't be such a big difference, since mongo has inbuilt caching mechanism and utilises maximum RAM.

Comment: I think you missed that latest displayed message is either from A to B or from B to A.  In other words you should see the latest message in correspondence regardless of direction.  I don't think your first collection can get that back with a single query - requires two queries.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Oops, I missed that part. Well if he needs extended functionality, then obviously he must pay by extra read :) Thanks friend :) I modified my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a schema like this for messages:

```
{ sender: userA,
  receip: userB,
  participants: [userA, userB],
  date: < >,
  message: "xxx"
}
```

If you index { participants:1, date: -1 } you can now use the index to find all records where userX was a participant, and you can use that index in an aggregation framework query like this:

```
db.messages.aggregate( [ 
    {$match:{participants:userX}}, 
    {$sort:{date:-1}}, 
    {$unwind:"$participants"}, 
    {$match:{participants:{$ne:userX}}, 
    {$group:{_id:"$participants", message:{$first:"$message"}, date: {$first:"$date"}} } 
] )
```

You don't need to keep an extra collection (so no extra writes) and aggregation query will use the index on participant, date for both the $match and the $sort operations, so it should be quite fast.

Comment: Yup, I agree, this is a good solution than what I suggested. Thanks mate :)